# Temporarily change background color for one tableview row [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

On the home screen of my app, I show a table view with URLs.

The user is able to add URLs from the clipboard, i.E. automatically and without needing to leave the home screen or pressing any buttons.

The new URL is then shown on top of the tableview, respectively.

If this behaviour runs, I would like to temporarily change the background color of the first tableview row (the one with the automatically added URL), to highlight it and inform the user explicitly, that the URL was stored.

I have a function in place, which runs after the URL was stored – but I don't know, how to change the background color of the first row for some seconds within this function. Could one assist?

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to store a kind of *state* that indicates that the first row needs to be highlighted.
- Then, call `reloadRows(at:with:)` to reload the first row/section
- This will call `cellForRow(at:)`, here you should evaluate the state and set the background color
- Also in that function, you could should up a timer (`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` or something) that will reset the state and call `reload` again after a given time
- After that time, `cellForRow(at:)` is being called and here the background color will be reset (since the state is different now).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm very stuck.

Inside the function which already checked if everything was stored successfully, I try:

let indexPath = [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)]
self.reportTable.reloadRows(at: indexPath, with: .fade)

... and then? I bet I'm doing it wrong. Sorry for noobing around. :/

Comment: I think it would be best if you add the relevant code parts to your question